# How to find mac address of laptop

Tags: mac-address

if I write 'ipconfig' command in windows 8 command prompt I get lots of physical address under several heading like "wireless lan adapter wi-fi", "ethernet adapter ethernet 2" etc. Under each of these heading there is a physical address and it is completely different from another.

And again if I write 'getmac' command I get a list of 6 physical addresses. I don't understand which one is the real physical address of my laptop. Please let me know how can I find which one is the real mac address of my laptop. Thanks

Comment: is this helpful? [https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=27309](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=27309)

Comment: Well your laptop doesn't have 1 mac address. That is why you're seeing so many. Every network device is going to have it's own mac address, so figure out which one you're using to connect to the internet (or network in question) and use that mac address.

Answer (score 1):

A laptop doesn't have a MAC address. [MAC address is a property of a network interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), such as LAN, WiFi etc. Therefore it is correct that you get different MAC addresses for different adapters.

If you just want to know the MAC address of the adapter currently in use, you can (in Windows 7):

1. Right-click the connection icon in the system tray
2. Open Network and sharing center
3. Next to Connections, click on the connection name.
4. In the Status window that appears, click Details...

You should then see the physical address of this specific adapter.

You can find screenshots [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-MAC-Address-of-Your-Computer).